# Creating a capability matching / peer selection component in JXTA?

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

I'm completely new to JXTA and just want some pointers to help get started.

I need to create a peer search / capability matching component, so I can search for and locate peers based on a number of custom criteria. In other words, peer A says 'I can do X, Y and K' and when peer B searches for peers that can do 'X and K', is able to discover peer A. Hope that makes sense.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to group peers by some high level criteria, perform searches for the group, and then search within the group for specific low-level capabilities.

I don't need hand holding, just some suggestions as to how to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to understand JXTA. The Practical JXTA II book has been made available on Scribd for reading. If your are looking for more advanced information, check the programmer's guide 2.6 & 2.7.

Regarding your application, you need to learn about advertisements and about creating (cutomized) peergroups under the netpeergroup (for a start).